# Mass change the appearance of URLs in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, url

I wish to change the appearance of the URLS in a Microsoft Excel worksheet. At present the  current URL's look something like: `http://www.example.com/101010101010101010101010101`. I know how to change the anchor text of the URLS by right clicking the worksheet and clicking 'hyperlink', this works however its less than ideal when working with worksheets with thousands of URLS.

I'd like to remove the full URL anchor text and replace it with ASCII `✔` but on a large scale and ensuring that the links still work.

***Question Summary***

*How do you change the appearance of thousand of URLs in Microsoft Excel?*

Comment: Can't you just do a search and replace? Search for `http://*` and replace with `✔`. If necessary, highlight columns to restrict which ones get changed.

Comment: Wouldn't that break the links?

Comment: No, it should only affect the displayed text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this small **VBA** macro:

```
Sub HyperFixer()
    Dim h As Hyperlink, r As Range
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        Set r = h.Parent
        h.TextToDisplay = "a"
        r.Font.Name = "Marlett"
    Next h
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**